How can we quantify "hardness to learn" for a general function in machine learning?
It's for sure that some functions are harder to learn than others. For example, a linear function is super easy to learn. However, a cryptographic encryption with secret key is unlearnable, and cannot be approximated with most neural networks.
Empirically, suppose there is an oracle to give data points $(x_i,y_i)$ where $y_i=f(x_i)$ for a function $f$ known by the oracle. And there is a learner who uses the data to learn $f$. There is clearly both computation overhead for the oracle and the learner (i.e. the oracle is basically doing inference and the learner is doing training), and the "hardness of learning" can be intuitively expressed by $\frac{\text{computation overhead for training}}{\text{computation overhead for inference}}$. However, theoretically, is there a notation or definition that can characterize this property of a function $f$?
Additionally, in practice, assuming good continuity and differentiability (i.e. can be approximated with neural networks), which functions are "harder to learn" and which functions are "easier to learn"?
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

which functions are "harder to learn" and which functions are "easier to learn" none... any set of $N$ points can be interpolated with a $N+1$ polynomial, so there is no concept of "hardest set of $N$ points to interpolate" (interpolate = loss being 0)
